# Как записывать и прослушивать звук?

Tags: android, аудио

В реальном времени, если такое стандартными средствами не возможно, то может есть либа какая - нибудь?

Live Audio Record. Чтобы записывать и одновременно прослушиывать, помогите пожалйуста. Незнаю как сделать.

Comment: Забудьте про "реальное время". Особенно на Android.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, а что так?. Почему забыть.

Comment: Запись с помощью MediaRecored, прослушивание с помощью MediaPlayer. Это все родные средства

Comment: @xTIGRx потому что ОС не является ОС реального времени. И все что в ней крутится - соответственно тоже. Захочет система дать задержку в 15 мкс перед открытием файла - даст. Захочет 2 секунды - тоже даст. И нет никакой гарантии, что задержка будет меньше определенного времени. Это не реальное время.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Но ведь такое и в Виндовс же происходит. Зависания.

Все же есть проги типо ютуба которые показывает видео сразу как загрузили в реальном времени. А не дожидаясь полной загрузки а после уже показывать. Вы так говорите будто IOS идеален...Одно и тоже Г

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, Дак а ка быть то.

Вот я написал прогу. нажал на кнопку записал. нажал прослушал.

А я хочу чтобы сразу нажал записал и слушал

Comment: Записывайте в поток, воспроизводите тут же из потока. Проблема у вас достаточно извращенная, я и представить не могу, зачем такое может быть надо. Подозреваю, что мало кому еще приходило в голову сделать такое, поэтому библиотеку вы вряд ли найдете

Comment: @metalurgus. Почему изврещщная. Вот мы рядом стоим. Я нажимаю на кнопку и вы в этот момент должны будете услышать мой голос. Вот и все. В реалном времени. А не после того как я запищу звук и отпущу кнопку

Comment: Я услышу ваш голос из вашего рта, если мы стоим рядом. Для этого ненужно его воспроизводить с записи.

Comment: @metalurgus, Ну я так то стою за углом дома, а расстояние от меня до вас 25 метров, вы не услышите. Так как у меня симкарта дажа входящие звонки не принимает, а денег нет. Но есть бесплатный интернет на месяц.

Comment: так вам что, через интернет нужно просто в реальном времени передавать звук?

Comment: @metalurgus, да через интернет. но главное чтобы я нажал на кнопку и звук сразу же передавался. А не так как в Zello. нажал -> сказал -> отпустил, только после этого передалось, так не надо, так я и сам сделать смогу. А вот в реальном времени не знаю даже как осущетсвить.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349987/stream-live-android-audio-to-server